# RESTfully adding multiple resources as sub-resources

Tags: rest

We have two (relevant) types in our system, items and collections.  These are identified by `ITEM-n` and `COLL-n` (where the `n`s are integers).

When we want to add a single item to a collection, we do the following:

```
PUT /collection/COLL-1234/items/ITEM-1234
```

However, we will sometimes be adding a large number of items to a collection, and would like to avoid many round-trips.  One option would be:

```
PUT /collection/COLL-1234/items
```

with a payload listing all of the items to add, but we *don't* want to replace all the items in the collection, so that doesn't quite work.

The best we've come up with is:

```
PATCH /collection/COLL-1234/items
```

with a payload listing all of the items.  Can anyone suggest anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` on the collection resource `/collection/COLL-1234/items`.

You are right that `PUT` is meant to *replace* the collection. But `POST` *creates* a new sub-resource. If the representation you `POST` is not *one* sub-resource but a *list* of sub-resource, this is OK, too.